# chaining to cast type in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
   let finalPrice = room.points[0].price.finalPrice //string
   finalPrice = +finalPrice //number
   finalPrice = finalPrice.toFixed(2) //2 decimal
```

Is it possible to shorten above type casting?

if I do

```
+room.points[0].price.finalPrice.toFixed(2)
```

I'll get this error: `toFixed is not a function`

Comment: `(+room.points[0].price.finalPrice).toFixed(2)` should do it.

Comment: `(+room.points[0].price.finalPrice).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
const finalPrice = Number(room.points[0].price.finalPrice).toFixed(2);
```

No need for intermediate variables.

The problem with your `+` is that it has lower operator precedence than the `.` with the `.toFixed` call.